# PHP erase files in a for loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of cars in my inventory, each can have up to 12 photos. I can successfully erase the car if I want to, what I am having trouble with is erasing the pictures as well.

So I can query something like this:

```
$pictures = "picture1, picture2, picture3, picture4, picture5, picture6, picture7, picture8, picture9, picture10, picture11, picture12";
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $pictures FROM `auto` WHERE `auto_id` = $autoid"));
```

With the `$data` variable, I can access the names of the picture like so `echo $data['picture1'];`

I'm trying to make for loop to loop through each picture, as long as the field in the db is not empty, create an array of those files paths from data and loop through the array erasing them using `unlink()`?

SO FAR SOLUTION [works but needs improvement?]

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']) === true)
{

    $pictures = "picture1, picture2, picture3, picture4, picture5, picture6, picture7, picture8, picture9,
    picture10, picture11, picture12";
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $pictures FROM `auto` WHERE `auto_id` = $autoid"));
    $a = 1;
    while ($a <= 12)
    {
        $picturepath = $data['picture'.$a];
        if (empty($picturepath) !== true)
        {
            unlink('../../' . $picturepath);
        }
        $a++;
    }

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `auto` WHERE `auto_id` = $autoid");
    header('Location: ../../admin.php?manage_vehicles');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: i take it the fields (columns) picture1, pcture2 etc contain the pathnames for the picture files?

Comment: does my solution contains any bad php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a for loop, appending the loop index value to the string 'picture' then use that to access the $data[] element.
Why bother though when you can simply do something like:

```
foreach ($data as $picname) {
  if (file_exists($picname) && is_file($picname)) unlink($picname);
}
```

easy.

ok let's have a look:
It's a minor thing but I prefer to use array_key_exists rather than isset and If not using the foreach, I would use a for loop and save yourself having to stipulate the picture[n] columns in the query string. So how about:

```
if (array_key_exists('delete',$_POST))
{
    // not needed
    // $pictures = "picture1, picture2, picture3, picture4, picture5, picture6, picture7,
    // picture8, picture9, picture10, picture11, picture12";
    // if $autoid is an integer, you can reduce the risk of sql injection by intval()
    // otherwise look at using preg_replace or using mysqli functions with prepare and bind_params
    $autoid=intval($autoid); 
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `auto` WHERE `auto_id` = $autoid"));
    if (!($res===false))
    {
      $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
      if (!($data===false))
      {
        for ($i=0; $i<=12; $i++)
        {
          $pic_col="picture$i";
          if (!array_key_exists("$pic_col",$data) || !strcmp(trim($data["$pic_col"]))) continue;
          $picname = '../../'.trim($data["$pic_col"]);
          if (file_exists($picname) && is_file($picname)) unlink($picname);
        }
      }
    }
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `auto` WHERE `auto_id` = $autoid");
    header('Location: ../../admin.php?manage_vehicles');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: thanks alot this is really good i actually did it a little different, check out my new code, any suggestion on combining your answer with my working solution @ArthurNicoll

Answer (score 0):

add a foreach loop after your query.

```
    foreach($data AS $photo)
    {
         if (!empty($photo) && file_exists($photo)) unlink($photo);
    }
```

updated answer, added file_exists()

Comment: i'm assuming $photo will be the url to the photo. might want to use file_exists() to double check if the file exists